# How can a Qt client talk to a Spring server application?

Tags: spring, qt

Is there any integration library/framework available? If not, what would be the best way to achieve this integration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with QT, that's a GUI framework.

Comment: I understand that Qt is a GUI framework, but to make a Qt client useful, it has to do other things: connect to DB, make HTTP request, etc. In my case, I need my Qt client to talk to an existing Spring server application. Otherwise, if your Qt client is just a GUI, what use does it have? Just for people to look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous integration options, but a thing that might be most suitable from a QT standpoint could be [SOAP](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsoap) or [REST](http://jgoday.wordpress.com/2009/04/13/rest-client-with-qt-45/). Both are supported in spring via [spring-ws](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/), or [spring-mvc](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) respectively. Another integration protocol that you might consider, but for one that I could not find direct QT support is [hessinan](http://hessian.caucho.com/), that has C++ client library.

Dig into [remoting chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) of the spring manual, to find a common ground.

Other than that there are the usual suspects (not spring or QT related):

1. google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)
2. facebook's [thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/)
3. [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture)
4. and a gazillion of others...

Comment: Yep, SOAP will do the work. Glad to know that Qt has SOAP support. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Be sure to checkout CXF (http://cxf.apache.org/) on the Java side for a very easy to configure / spring enabled SOAP stack.